# Calling a method <name> I get AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute <name>

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have a callback method being triggered on a GPIO pin that when fired calls for a read of a input devices register, however when called I get -

> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/home/coder/Try2.py", line 35, in NewPins
> > >           x = self.mcp.readGPIO()
> > >       AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'mcp'

If I enter- 
    `a.mcp.readGPIO()`  <- from python shell I get

```
`BitArray('0xffff')`  <-expected result
>>>
```

where the RotaryEncoder class is instantiated as 'a'

```
 `class RotaryEncoder:`
   `def __init__(self,IntPin, Start, Id):`
     .... initialise some variables then open the device as 'mcp' -
   `self.mcp = MCP23S17(bus=0x00, pin_cs=0x00, device_id=Id)`
   `self.mcp.open()`
   `def NewPins(self):`
   `   global OldPins`
   `   x = self.mcp.readGPIO()`
        ..... irrelevant code
```

callback line is 
    `gpio.add_event_detect(IntPin, gpio.FALLING, callback=NewPins)`

expected read value is a BitArray
actual result is 
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'mcp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok my dumb.... - the RPiGPIO library I'm using returns the GPIO channel number in the callback, hence the callback function requires two arguments and not one. I had thought I'd messed up my namespaces and so was trying to code around this when I encountered the error above - I'm a novice python programmer and didn't know where to look!
That'll teach me to not to read the documentation thoroughly...